# as400 crtcmd command not created in library

Tags: command, ibm-midrange, cl

I am making my own command, and so far the cl code that processes the .cmd code works just fine on its own. I can call it and send in the parameters and it does exactly what it needs to do, so I'm assuming that the error must be with the .cmd:

```
CMD 'DISPLAY SYSTEM LEVEL (DSPSYSLVL) NADIA S.C.'
PARM KWD(OUTPUT)
MIN(1)
TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8)
RSTD(*YES)
VALUES(*MSGLINE *DISPLAY)
PROMPT('OUTPUT FOR SYSTEM LEVEL')

PARM KWD(SOLUTION)
TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(4)
RSTD(*YES)
VALUES(*YES *NO)
DFT(*NO)
PROMPT('TELL ME HOW YOU DID IT')

PARM KWD(SHOWCMD)
TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(4)
RSTD(*YES)
VALUES(*YES *NO)
DFT(*NO)
PROMPT('SHOW COMMAND')
```

when I run `crtcmd` and give the appropriate filenames, I get the message "Command DSPSYSLVL not created in library [library name]." with a CPF0201 message.

I'm still fairly new to the whole system, and I'm really not sure what the problem could be. The job log doesn't provide any new information either...

Comment: There should be a spool file generated by the CRTCMD compiler, which will list whatever errors it encountered.

Comment: The `CPF0201` error message includes a "Recovery" section. What did you find when you followed its instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may just be a transcription issue but the first thing that stands out is the multi-line format without the continuation character (+):

```
CMD 'DISPLAY SYSTEM LEVEL (DSPSYSL'
PARM KWD(OUTPUT) +
MIN(1) + 
TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(8) +
RSTD(*YES) +
VALUES(*MSGLINE *DISPLAY) +
PROMPT('OUTPUT FOR SYSTEM LEVEL')

PARM KWD(SOLUTION) +
TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(4) +
RSTD(*YES) +
VALUES(*YES *NO) +
DFT(*NO) +
PROMPT('TELL ME HOW YOU DID IT')

PARM KWD(SHOWCMD) +
TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(4) +
RSTD(*YES) +
VALUES(*YES *NO) +
DFT(*NO) +
PROMPT('SHOW COMMAND')
```

Each `PARM` is a single entity and must be 'continued' if split onto multiple lines.

The `CRTCMD` command should generate a spooled file containing more details about the errors.

**EDIT:** Also the maximum length of the `CMD` prompt is 30 characters.

Comment: Perfect! The continuation character was exactly the problem, thank you very much.